# Query Performance - Fetch rows where subfiles are not being fetched from the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a web based file explorer where the details of files and folders are stored in the database and are shared with Active Directory users or groups. When I have to bind the grid with shared files, it takes a lot of time if files are more because I first fetch all the files and then remove the subfiles / subdirectories rows. How can I ignore the subfiles / subdirectories so that the performance will increase?

This is a sample table of the files to which the user has permissions.

```
id |    path                                  |    name         |    parent                      |    isdirectory
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    /data/user1/folder1                   |    folder1      |    /data/user1                 |    true
2  |    /data/user1/folder1/text1.txt         |    text1.txt    |    /data/user1/folder1         |    false
3  |    /data/user1/folder1/folder2           |    folder2      |    /data/user1/folder1         |    true
4  |    /data/user1/folder1/folder2/text2.txt |    text2.txt    |    /data/user1/folder1/folder2 |    false
5  |    /data/user2/paper.pdf                 |    paper.pdf    |    /data/user2                 |    false
5  |    /data2/backup/reports                 |    reports      |    /data2/backup               |    true
6  |    /data2/backup/reports/rep1.pdf        |    rep1.pdf     |    /data2/backup/reports       |    false
7  |    /softwaredump                         |    softwaredump |    /                           |    true
8  |    /softwaredump/win10.iso               |    win10.iso    |    /softwaredump               |    false
```

Now as you can see that there are subfiles and folders in this table. So while binding the grid, I use this query

```
WITH finally AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        Parent
        FROM
        files m1
    WHERE Parent NOT IN (
        SELECT Path FROM files WHERE Path LIKE CONCAT(@Path,'/%')
        )
    )
SELECT *
FROM files fin
    INNER JOIN finally ON finally.Parent = fin.Parent
    WHERE fin.Path LIKE CONCAT(@Path,'/%')
```

Here `@Path` is the SP Parameter to browse the path, default being `''` and later on say `'/data/user1/folder1'` for browsing that folder

Expected output as I am getting.

```
id |    path                                  |    name         |    parent                      |    isdirectory
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    /data/user1/folder1                   |    folder1      |    /data/user1                 |    true
5  |    /data/user2/paper.pdf                 |    paper.pdf    |    /data/user2                 |    false
5  |    /data2/backup/reports                 |    reports      |    /data2/backup               |    true
7  |    /softwaredump                         |    softwaredump |    /                           |    true
```

I have also added a Non-clustered index. For about 15000 files, this query takes about 20-30 seconds.

However, as number of files increase, the performance decreases. The solution for that would be to select only the top most level and ignore the subfiles and subfolders. But when a file is shared, it becomes the topmost level and it has no sublevel.

Here is a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/588c7/1/0).

Comment: What have created the index on?

Comment: I have created `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on ID column

Comment: But all your selection criteria are on Path and Parent columns. That's where the indexes are going to be most valuable.

Comment: @TomC I have some other selections based on ID too. Should I create two more Unique Non-clustered Indexes on Path and Parent?

Comment: Well they wont be unique. Just a standard create index will do.